# Laravel container doesn't resolve Test methods dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, inversion-of-control

I have a test suit for a **CLI** program created in `App\Commands` namespace. The problem I have is that it seems laravel container doesn't resolve test method dependencies nor laravel helpers, ... . I'm on **Windows 10**.

**PHP code :**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use ACME\SomeClass;

class CLICommandTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    protected $key = '';
    protected $someClass = null;

    public function __construct(SomeClass $someClass)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->someClass = $someClass;
        $this->key = config('someconfig')['key'];
    }

    /*
     * test handle method
     */
    public function testHandle()
    {
        //assertions
    }

}
```

I've created & included the service provider for this :

```
<?php

use ACME\SomeClass;

$this->app->bind('ACME\SomeClass', function($app){
    return new SomeClass($value);
});
```

when I run `phpunit` from either `PATH` or `vendor/bin` this error comes up :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CLICommandTest::__construct() must be an instance of ACME\SomeClass, none given, called in phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 475 and defined in C:\path\tests\CLICommandTest.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php(475): CLICommandTest->__construct()
#1 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php(880): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest(Object(ReflectionClass), 'testHandle')
#2 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php(195): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod(Object(ReflectionClass), Object(ReflectionMethod))
#3 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php(297): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct(Object(ReflectionClass))
#4 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php(381): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite(Object(ReflectionClass))
#5 phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuit in C:\path\tests\CLICommandTest.php on line 16

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CLICommandTest::__construct() must be an instance of ACME\SomeClass, none given, called in phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 475 and defined in C:\path\tests\CLICommandTest.php on line 16

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CLICommandTest::__construct() must be an instance of ACME\SomeClass, none given, called in phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 475 in C:\path\tests\CLICommandTest.php on line 16

Call Stack:
    0.0036     492584   1. {main}() C:\PHPUnit\phpunit:0
    0.1375    8875000   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\PHPUnit\phpunit:515
    0.1375    8878160   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:106
    0.1375    8878160   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:117
    0.1624   10379328   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:663
    0.1624   10379912   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php:796
    0.1651   10381496   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php:885
    0.1651   10381496   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:409
    0.1732   10916648   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:381
    0.1732   10917104  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:297
    0.1733   10982344  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:195
    0.1733   10982760  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:880
    0.1735   10986272  13. CLICommandTest->__construct() phar://C:/PHPUnit/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:475
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: Case matters. `use ACME\SomeClass` in your test.

Comment: @AlexBlex what do you mean? this is a test name. the Case is CamelCase in real code and the logic works. the problem is that IoC doesn't resolve dependencies for `tests/*`

Comment: See my answer below, does it make more sense?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `use` block name of the class should match:

```
<?php

use ACME\SomeClass; // <== see, it should be SomeClass here, not someClass

$this->app->bind('ACME\SomeClass', function($app){
    return new SomeClass($value); 
});
```

Apart from that, your `class CLICommandTest extends TestCase` in fact extends [\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php). Its constructor signature is:

```
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
```

Where first argument is name of the test, and it is optional. Your

```
public function __construct(SomeClass $someClass)
```

overwrites the signature with much stricter requirement: first parameter is mandatory and it must have type `SomeClass`. It brakes the contract, so test runner cannot instantiate the testcase.

I would suggest to read [Laravel testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing) and [PHPUnit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) to understand how to write tests and why you rarely need to extend constructor.

It look like you want too use [setUp/tearDown](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) methods:

```
class CLICommandTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions; // <== please double check you need the trait here

    protected $key = '';
    protected $someClass = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        // here you probably want to create an instance of your application 

        $this->someClass = new SomeClass;
        $this->key = 'value of the key';
    }
    ...
```

Comment: No my friend. I told you that in my real code its all CamelCased. this is a test code that I made up to simulate the real issue

Comment: this is true if I want to pass the dependency to the `parent` class. but here I'm injecting to a simple class constructor that has a custom signature regardless of its ancestors.

Comment: First of all, changing parent's signature is not a good thing to do, unfortunately sometimes possible in PHP. Secondly, phpunit knows nothing about laravel, including your dependencies. Please read the links. The key point to understand there, is your tests are not your application. I have updated answer with some assumptions.

Comment: I haven't changed the parent signature, but thanks for the links and your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and phpunit are separate frameworks. Only in certain parts of a laravel application (controllers, events etc) can you pass in class dependencies and the service container will resolve them. phpunit has nothing to do with this.

Though you can still harness the container by using the helper function:

```
$someObject = app()->make(SomeClass::class);
```

However for testing you may want to mock the object rather than build it from scratch, in which case use the Mockery library.